# Solve: $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{2x-2}}$

Tags: calculus

I converted the rational equation into $\frac{(x+2)^\frac{1}{2}}{(2x-2)^\frac{1}{2}}$

and since both top and bottom have the same power, I took the coefficeints of the largst power term.

My answer is 1/2 but the answer in the book is √2/2. What have I done wrong?

Comment: You ignored the square roots.

Answer (score 5):

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{2x-2}}
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{2x-2}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{2(x-1)}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac{(x-1)+2}{2(x-1)}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac12+\frac{1}{x-1}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac12+\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x-1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{2x-2}}\\=\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt\frac{x+2}{2x-2}\\=\sqrt{\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x+2}{2x-2}}\\=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\\=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{2x-2}}=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}}{\sqrt{2-\frac{2}{x}}}=\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1+2h}}{\sqrt{2-2h}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}=\dots$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way: 'pull' $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ from the denominator and rewrite the fraction as $\frac{x-1+3}{x-1} = 1 +\frac{3}{x-1}$, and you get the result immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps
\[
\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{2x-2}}=
\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{2(x-1)}}
\]
\[
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x-1}}=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{\frac{(x-1)+3}{x-1}}
\]
\[
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{1+\frac{3}{x-1}}=\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\]